# Include native binaries in JAR (issues w/ maven-shade-plugin)

Tags: java-native-interface, executable-jar, maven-shade-plugin

I am building a library that requires an SO file.

My goals:

- automatically pick up the SO file from the artifact repository
- include it as a resource in the installed JAR so that I do not need to add it manually and therefore not have to also put in the GitHub repository.

I am referencing it in my library POM like this:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myco.mygrp</groupId>
        <artifactId>native</artifactId>
        <type>so</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

This does add it to my local Maven repository but when I attempt to build an uber JAR from a second project that is a client to this project and therefore imports it and references it in its POM, I get

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:3.2.4:shade (default) on project i-am-the-client: Error creating shaded jar: **error in opening zip file** /Users/me/.m2/repository/com/myco/mygrp/0.0.1/native-0.0.1.so -> [Help 1]

While I want that SO file in my client uber JAR, I don't need it to be unzipped or opened. **How do I get `maven-shade-plugin` to include it in the JAR but without treating the SO file like it's a JAR to be unzipped?** Here's the `maven-shade-plugin` for reference:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.myco.somegrp.Client</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>scala/tools/nsc/doc/html/resource/lib/jquery*</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I can circumvent this by just adding the native SO into the resources directory manually but that will go against one of the goals and also raise eyebrows during code review because, per the goal, the binary is already in Nexus and is not necessarily wanted in GitHub as well.

As a secondary approach, I resort to my `maven-dependency-plugin` as so:

```xml
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.myco.mygrp</groupId>
                            <artifactId>native</artifactId>
                            <type>so</type>
                            <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                            <destFileName>my_native.so</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

When I `mvn install`, I get the expected "my_native.so" file in target/lib but not in the installed JAR. **I would like to have this file included in the installed JAR so that it can be loaded up by the JNI code.**    I intend to `System.load` it up even if it is in the same JAR by writing it out to a temp file in the file system right before and loading that temp file instead.
I have been working on this for some days including scouring the interwebs before I settled upon this strategy but I am open to suggestions if this is the wrong approach.

Comment: You can put them in there, but they won't work. The operating system requires them to be in the file system.

Comment: Thanks! I have it so that it writes it into the file system from the JAR right before loading. Do you know how to put it in the JAR from the artifact repo?